# 90s (or earlier) short story involving a process of cellular cleaning that involved temporarily liquifying someone into a swimming pool

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember two parts of the story in question:

- the protagonist was temporarily liquefied and expanded enough to fill a swimming pool while his cells underwent some kind of cleaning or surveillance
- afterwards, when the protagonist plucked his eyelashes they would give a kind of static or electric "pop"; if I remember correctly he did this to pass the time

The likeliest place for me to have read this would be in an issue of Asimov's magazine in the early to mid-90s (and second-likeliest would have been a "best science fiction short stories" anthology from the same timeframe).

Thanks to the answers to my last question I knew to first search for `[story-identification] swimming pool` and `[story-identification] eyelash` but didn't find any likely results. :)

Comment: Something like this happened in Sheri S. Tepper's late 1990's novel _[Six Moon Dance](https://www.harpercollins.com/9780062035011/six-moon-dance/)_.

Comment: @Spencer - So post it as an answer then!

Comment: @Valorum OP wants a short story.

Comment: @Spencer - OP is invariably wrong about everything. Post it and be damned if you think it's a reasonable fit.

Comment: @Spencer I searched through a copy of Six Moon Dance for cells, eyelash, eyebrow, swimming pool, etc. and came up empty-handed--if you have a pointer to the section in question though I'd be happy to read it to see if it jogs anything else loose though :)

Comment: @Valorum _sigh_ back upstairs to the boxes...

Comment: @Beau not so much a swimming pool, as a swimming pool-sized puddle of alien slime in a cave.

Comment: Blokes plucking eyebrows? .....weird

Comment: @DannyMcG what's weird about it? I'd have a unibrow otherwise :P

Comment: Also not a short story, but temporarily liquefying people happens in Piers Anthony's novel Macroscope - the purpose was for the protagonists to survive the high acceleration of a fast transit from Earth orbit to Neptune orbit.

Comment: Comment because I do not know title - I have read this as both a short story in Asimov's or a standalone novel.  Title similar to "It was the best of times".  Protagonist was a Christmas/party-box-wrapper artist who fell in love with a politician who became President.  Home Guard or political party wanted control over the President, so they used crime-fighting genetic slugs to accuse the protagonist of being a major criminal.  After his body was put into pool and back, the protagonist was "seared", i.e., made non-immortal (parts self-immolate).  He volunteered to go to Mars as punishment.

Comment: @jhpace1 that all sounds familiar! we're on the right track...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story is "We Were Out of Our Minds with Joy", by David Marusek, published in Asimov's November 1995 issue, and [readable here in the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/asimovsv19n1213199511/page/n89?q=%22we+were+out+of+our+minds+with+joy%22).

It was also expanded on and published as a book (as jhpace1 mentioned in his comment) as [Counting Heads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/499429.Counting_Heads).

Re: cellular disassembly in a swimming pool:

> “Any one of those conditions gave them the authority they needed.
>   They didn’t have the patience to read you slow and gentle like, so they
>   pumped you so full of smartactives you filled a swimming pool.”

Re: eyelashes (actually eyebrows):

> So I spend my days sitting in the dim dampness of my basement corner, growing pasty white and fat (twenty pounds already), and plucking
>   my eyebrows to watch them sizzle like fuses.