# Which Sci-Fi work introduced the concept of "AI Doctor"?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

We see AI doctors in Sci-Fi works all the time. Examples can be the famous medical droids of *Star Wars* (first encounter 1980):

[image: GH-7 Medical Droid] [image: 2-1B Surgical Droid] [image]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

The Doctor (Emergency Medical Hologram Mark I) from *Star Trek: Voyager* (1995) is an even better example because it didn't have a physical body. I believe I've also encountered AI doctors in *Doctor Who* several times, but I can't recall an example.

Which Sci-Fi work first explored the concept of an AI doctor?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for an _AI_ doctor (which may not be able to do physical manipulations, but only consult/diagnose) or a _robot_ doctor (which may not be fully intelligent, but able to treat a wide range of illnesses).  There are a lot of older stories featuring something like an "autodoc" which is a machine that heals without being self-aware.

Comment: @DavidW Physical body is not necessary. But, if it's a robot, it needs to be self aware (complete AI).

Comment: was the Voyager The Doctor self aware? I seem to remember that it believed to be real, or at least not an AI?

Comment: You would definitely need to give evidence that the Star Wars medical droids were self-aware.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, those images are massive so we don't want them taking up the whole page.

Comment: @DJClayworth There was at least one canon medical droid (https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/2-1B_Delta) that defected from the Empire for moral reasons and what dialogue they have in the films is pretty sentient-sounding. The rule of thumb for Star Wars seems to be that droids, especially human-looking ones, are self-aware unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Rex by Harl Vincent (1934) features a robot surgeon who becomes self aware

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Your resizing is destroying background transparency.

Comment: @CaptainCold That’s imgur acting up but I’d rather have a black background than a massive image.

Answer (score 5):

["The Little Black Bag"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Black_Bag) by Cyril Kornbluth (1950) featured a set of futuristic medical tools sent from the future to the present day (as of writing). These tools were sufficiently automated and intelligent enough to allow an untrained 18-year-old to use them.

Answer (score 4):

The ***"[autodoc](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=264)"*** appeared in many stories set in [Larry Niven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Niven)'s "Known Space" future history setting

Niven's first use of the term "autodoc" is in his short story "[The Warriors](https://www.you-books.com/book/L-Niven/The-Warriors)", which appeared in *Worlds of If* in 1966 (and which incidentally is the first appearance of the Kzinti).

> Jim Davis had come into view. The *Angel’s Pencil* had left Earth when he was twenty-seven; now he was a slightly paunchy thirty-eight, the oldest man on board, an amiable man with abnormally long, delicate fingers. His grandfather, with the same hands, had been a world-famous surgeon. Nowadays surgery was normally done by **autodocs**, and the arachnodactyls were to Davis merely an affliction.

Comment: To repeat:  Note that this was *specifically* the intent of my request for clarification, and the OP *expressly* ruled it out as an answer. (I even referenced the term "autodoc.")

Comment: @DavidW This sort of situation is why deleting a reasonable answer is usually a bad idea. Anyway, to paraphrase Valorum from the commentary on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221765/90s-or-earlier-short-story-involving-a-process-of-cellular-cleaning-that-invol), OP is invariably wrong about everything.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, even if it seems a bit crufty. On the other hand it wasn't my intention to pressure Zeiss Ikon into deleting the previous answer either, and if the situation were reversed I likely would have deleted an answer of mine for the same reason...

Comment: @DavidW I've received more than one lecture about responding to a question as it appears in OP.   Also, Captain Cold's reply to your request in comments, rather than in the question itself, would have resulted in several downvotes on many other SE sites.

Comment: @spencer Niven's stories were my first thought as well, but Keith Laumer had something very similar in *A Plague of Demons* in 1965.